# Conda doesn't work and every time I reinstall it throws a different error

Tags: python, seaborn, conda

I apologize in advance for the bad question title but I really do not know how to phrase it.

I had problems with conda always freezing on "solving environment" and tried some things to fix it. This ultimately caused some version conflicts in existing scripts so I had to removed conda (via deleting the anaconda3 folder from home). A collegue told me to try and install conda with sudo rights this time which I tried. This caused some other issues so and I read that it is generally not advised, so I uninstalled again (via deleting anaconda3 folder) and reinstalled in my home directory without sudo.

Since then I have not been able to create an environment which can import seaborn or matplotlib and have installed and reinstalled multiple times and I get a different error every time.

Last time I had the following:

```
ImportError: /home/terra/anaconda3/bin/../lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.30'
```

even though I did have GLIBCXX_3.4.30. I tried all suggested solutions (linking gcc explicitly, updating everything, looking for a double installation and etc) and it didn't work. I reinstalled again. Now I am getting:

```
ImportError: cannot import name '_imaging' from 'PIL' (/home/terra/anaconda3/envs/tgt_analysis/lib/pypy3.9/site-packages/PIL/__init__.py)
```

I honestly have no idea how to fix this issue and the sort of randomness and frequence of issues suggests to me that I messed up something when I installed conda with sudo and now have environment bleed through which i have no idea how to resolve.

I am doing this on ubuntu 22 and every time I reinstall I create a new environment like this:

```
conda install --name test_env python jupyter numpy scipy pandas seaborn pingouin statsannotation pyro-ppl
```

Any advice on how to diagnose and fix the issue would be much appreciated cause I haven run out of ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's important to ensure that you have completely removed any remnants of previous Conda installations. Deleting the anaconda3 folder is a good start, but there might be other system-wide configurations or environment variables that need to be cleaned up as well. Try the following:

- Check if there are any lingering Conda-related environment variables.
  Open a terminal and run the command: echo $PATH. Make sure that there
  are no references to the previous Conda installation.
- Check if there are any other environment variables related to Conda.
  Run the command: echo $CONDA_PREFIX. If it returns any path, it means
  there is still some configuration remaining. Unset the environment
  variable by running: unset CONDA_PREFIX.
- Additionally, you can check if there are any other Conda-related
  files or directories present. Look for files like .condarc or .conda
  in your home directory (~), and remove them if found.

Once you have ensured that the previous installation is completely removed, let's proceed with a fresh installation of Conda:

- Download the latest Miniconda installer for Linux from the official website (https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/miniconda.html). Choose the appropriate installer for your architecture (e.g., 64-bit or 32-bit).
- Open a terminal, navigate to the directory where you downloaded the Miniconda installer, and run the following command to make it executable: chmod +x Miniconda*.sh.
- Run the installer using the command: ./Miniconda*.sh. Follow the prompts to complete the installation. Make sure to choose the installation location as your home directory (~) and not system-wide (avoid using sudo).
- Once the installation is complete, close and reopen the terminal to ensure that the changes take effect.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response! I uninstalled conda again and this is what my PATH looks like:

/home/terra/anaconda3/bin:/home/terra/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/snap/bin

I need to remove only the explicit anaconda3 reference, yes?

Comment: Open the .bashrc file with the command `nano ~/.bashrc` . There probably is a section for conda where the path export is happening. Should look contain something like this: `export PATH="home/terra/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"`. Delete the whole section that is for the conda setup.

Comment: Yes, I did this and commented out the whole code block and installled miniconda but I cannot seem to run conda commands. Miniconda was not in the PATH, so I added the following line to my .bashrc:  export PATH="/home/miniconda3/bin/:$PATH" and now it is added but I still cannot execute conda commands. EDIT: I forgot to add my username....... it is working now, going to create an environment and report back.

Comment: I had to uncomment the conda init part of the .bashrc and manually change the url to miniconda rather than anaconda and it seems to work now. Thank you!

Comment: That's good to hear, glad I could help!